# BigQuery - ST_MAKEPOLYGON() fail with invalid polygon loop

Tags: google-bigquery, gis

I followed the brilliant post  [How to Catch ST_MAKEPOLYGON Error in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54361149/how-to-catch-st-makepolygon-error-in-bigquery)
which eliminate most of the problems, but i still run into an edge situation where the ST_MAKEPOLYGONS() failed with:

> Invalid polygon loop.

[image]

My question is twofold.

- What is the meaning of the error message.
- How can I detect such a situation in order to avoid this type of error.

I followed the advice in referenced post, and also introduced another preventive measure, but still run into a problem.

```
-- remove invalid ratio
    SELECT * 
    FROM(SELECT *,
         SAFE_DIVIDE(ST_DISTANCE(centroid, anchor) , ST_DISTANCE(centroid, location)) AS ratio 
         FROM X4) 
         WHERE ratio BETWEEN -1 AND 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the meaning of the error message.

The error means the input of the function is invalid, as defined by [Simple Feature Access standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Features) (either ISO or OGC version). The polygon should be described as a shell (a loop with no self-intersections) and optionally holes (again, a loop with no self-intersections, holes cannot cross each other or the shell either).

You have duplicate vertices and thus self-intersections in the loop. This often means a figure-8 loop. This is not a valid polygon, such shape should be described by two polygons instead, with a separate polygon representing each circle in "8".

I.e. `POLYGON((0 0, 1 1, 2 0, 2 2, 1 1, 0 2, 0 0))` is not correct, but `MULTIPOLYGON(((0 0, 1 1, 0 2, 0 0)), ((1 1, 2 0, 2 2, 1 1)))` is correct, even though some tools might show them identically.

How you fix this input in practice depends on where the data comes from and how it  is generated. If you just want to detect and bypass the error in a few rows, use `SAFE.ST_MakePolygon` - it returns NULL instead of failing, so at least the other rows will be OK.

Comment: Thanks the safe call did help.  I wonder if you can think of a way to detect those "8" shape polygons before attempting to make them.